# Parsing of badly formatted HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, sax

In my code I convert some styled xls document to html using openoffice.
I then parse the tables using `xml_parser_create`.
The problem is that openoffice creates oldschool html with unclosed `<BR>` and `<HR>` tags, it doesn't create doctypes and don't quote attributes `<TABLE WIDTH=4>`.

The php parsers I know off don't like this, and yield xml formatting errors. My current solution is to run some regexes over the file before I parse it, but this is neither nice nor fast.

Do you know a (hopefully included) php-parser, that doesn't care about these kinds of mistakes? Or perhaps a fast way to fix a 'broken' html?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution to "fix" broken HTML could be to use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) *(quoting)* :

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
> HTML filter library written in  PHP.
>
> HTML Purifier will not only remove
> all malicious  code (better known as
> XSS) with a thoroughly audited,
> secure yet permissive whitelist, it
> **will also make sure your documents are  standards compliant**

An alternative idea might be to try loading your HTML with [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`][2] *(quoting)* :

> The function parses the HTML contained
> in the string source . Unlike loading
> XML, **HTML does not have to be
> well-formed** to load.

And if you're trying to load HTML from a file, see [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php).

Comment: +1 for introduction htmlpurifier.
one may look at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ too.

Comment: The purifier is nice, but feels like kinda overkill for the problem. Same thing goes for the DOMParser. Is it not correct, that it will require a lot more time and ram than a simple sax parser?

Comment: Maybe it will require more RAM, and possibly time ; but it will do more than a simple SAX parse, that would only read data, and not repair it ;;; and I'd say a SAX parser will only be able to read valid XML -- while HTMLPurifier and `DOMDocument::loadHTML` are both able to read "broken" HTML.

Comment: Because my errors are always generated by the same engine, and thus fairly predictable, I've coded the parser using simple regex.
I know about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454 and I am very thankful for pointing me to these two great tools.

Comment: If you can "predict" the errors, I guess that's OK :-) You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is [SimpleHTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

For repairing broken HTML, you could use [Tidy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

As an alternative you can use the native [XML Reader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php). Because it is acts as a cursor going forward on the document stream and stopping at each node on the way, it will not break on invalid XML documents.

See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-pullparsingphp.html

Comment: +1 for Tidy. I find it's more robust at it's job than SimpleHTML. 2 separate tools for 2 different jobs really.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you're still using the PHP 4 XML API?

If you can get away with using PHP 5's XML API, there are two possibilities.

First, try the built-in HTML parser. It's really not very good (it tends to choke on poorly formatted HTML), but it might do the trick. Have a look at DomDocument::LoadHTML.

Second option - you could try the HTML parser based on the HTML5 parser specification:

http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/

This tends to work better than the built-in PHP HTML parser. It loads the HTML into a DomDocument object.

Comment: I'd rather not use a dom parser, as the document is quite big. (And I've already written tons of code for the sax)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use DOMDocument.

Example :

```
$str = "
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  </div>error.
  <p>another error</i>
 </body>
</html>
";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($str);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Advantage : natively included in PHP, contrary to PHP Tidy.