# PHP import XML remove any un-opened or un-closed divs?

Tags: php

Im importing an XML feed as content onto my page with PHP. If the content has a spare open or closed div then it messes up my page:

```
<div>
<div>Stuff</div>
<div>Stuff</div>
<div>Stuff</div>
```

Or

```
<div>Stuff</div>
<div>Stuff</div>
<div>Stuff</div>
</div>
```

I cant remove all divs as they are needed for the layout of the content. With php can I remove any divs that either open but dont close, or close but dont open? Thanks

Comment: Search is your friend.  Have a look at this very similar question: [Parsing of badly formated HTML in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351526/parsing-of-badly-formated-html-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most effective solution would probably be the use of the [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) extension. It has several methods which will allow you to clean and repair markup.

In particular, you would want to look at [tidy::cleanRepair](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.cleanrepair.php), which should remove any broken tags, and produce "clean" output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php), but as I understand it works best on complete pages.