# Issue capturing paragraph not enclosed in html tags using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to use Simple HTML DOM Parser to extract some html from a page. I am able to pull in the page with this code:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

and am able to pull different elements without issue. What I can't figure out is if the text is not enclosed in a tag, how to capture it.

What selector or coding can I use to capture the paragraph just below the p tags?

```
<h3>
    Business Description</h3>
<p>
    <b>
        One line description of business
    </b>
</p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...
```

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351526/parsing-of-badly-formated-html-in-php - the answer there probably applies here.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that this is section pulled from a page and the entire section as well as a bunch of other content is located inside a div tag so I don't think the html formatting is an issue unless I misunderstood what was being suggested. The issue I have is trying to select the paragraph and not the rest of the content inside the div tag.

Comment: If the structure is consistent, can you remove the content inside tags to leave that outside tags?